# Place part of the navbar brand outside the bar

Tags: vue.js

I really don't know how to make a good title for this but what I want basically is this:

[image]

But what I'm having as a result is this

[image]

Here's the code I have for the navbar. I am using Bootstrap Vue library

```
    .logo-home{
        width:50px;
        height:50px;
    }

.navbar-fh{
    background-color:#BAE5FF !important;
}
```

```
    <div>
        <b-navbar toggleable="lg" type="light" variant="secondary" class="navbar-fh">
            <b-navbar-brand to="/"> <img src="../../../public/LogoV1.png" alt="" class="logo-home">
            </b-navbar-brand>

            <b-navbar-toggle target="nav-collapse"></b-navbar-toggle>

            <b-collapse id="nav-collapse" is-nav>

                <!-- Right aligned nav items -->
                <b-navbar-nav class="ml-auto">
                    <b-nav-item to="/">Home</b-nav-item>
                    <b-nav-item to="/two">Page Two</b-nav-item>
                </b-navbar-nav>
            </b-collapse>
        </b-navbar>
    </div>
```

Is there any way I could make it look like the first image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change positioning of your logo to `absolute` and position it with `top`/`left` properties as you want:

```
.logo-home{
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
}
```

And don't forget to move down menu items for mobile mode. Add class (e.g. `menu-items`) to your `b-navbar-nav` (like `<b-navbar-nav class="ml-auto menu-items">`) with the following styles:

```
@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .menu-items {
    margin-top: 40px;
  }
}
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app"
});
```

```css
.logo-home{
        width:60px;
        height:60px;
        background-color: blue;
        position: absolute;
        top: 20px;
    }

@media (max-width: 991px) {
   .menu-items{
        margin-top: 40px;
    }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.0.0-rc.11/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.0.0-rc.11/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <b-navbar toggleable="lg" type="light" variant="secondary" class="navbar-fh">
    <b-navbar-brand to="/">
      <div class="logo-home"></div>
    </b-navbar-brand>

    <b-navbar-toggle target="nav-collapse"></b-navbar-toggle>
    <b-collapse id="nav-collapse" is-nav>
      <!-- Right aligned nav items -->
      <b-navbar-nav class="ml-auto menu-items">
        <b-nav-item to="/">Home</b-nav-item>
        <b-nav-item to="/two">Page Two</b-nav-item>
      </b-navbar-nav>
    </b-collapse>
 </b-navbar>
</div>
```

Comment: It's probably not a good idea to modify `ml-auto`, you should add the styling to a custom class

Comment: @Hiws Thank you for your note. I don't work with Bootstrap, so I didn't know that `ml-auto` is Bootstrap's class. I added a custom class according to your advice.